# Display form in Django not based on Models/Form

Tags: python, django

My view calls some backend classes which need some user input. When user input is required, i halt processing and store the questions into the session - `request.session['questions']`. `request.session['questions']` is a list of dictionaries. e.g.

```
request.session['question'] = []
request.session['question'].append({'question' : 'Whats your firstname', 'answer' : ''})
request.session['question'].append({'question' : 'Whats your firstname', 'answer' : ''})
```

I need to display these questions to the user along with an input box for each question. When the user submits the form, I need to dump the input into the answers part of the session variable. Could someone show me how to do this? I'm a little lost as this isn't really based on Django forms or models as such.

Thanks

Comment: Before anwering, what is the reason for not using models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) that aren't associated with models, like this:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    answer = forms.CharField()

def questions(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')
    else:
        form = QuestionForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('questions.html', {'form': form,})
```

More documentation [here](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2010/01/doing-things-with-django-forms/).